# Get back a variable in a style balise with a loadTemplate

Tags: jquery

I'm in trouble for one week. I want to get back a variable in a balise style(url) in my template:

```
<div class="project" style="background:url({{asset(project.image.path) | imagine_filter('medium')}}) no-repeat center center / cover">.
```

In my controller - I work with Symfony 3 - I get the image path , which is a variable, of course:

```
 > if($lcp->getProject()->getImage()){ $i = $lcp->getProject()->getImage(); $projectImagePath = $i->getPath(); }else{ $projectImagePath = null; }
```

I don't know how I could get the $projectImagePath in my div in twig !! Is it possible ?

Comment: What is "balise" you mentioned in the title? Where are you using `loadTemplate` in your code? Edit your question to make it easy for readers to understand what are you talking about.

Comment: Sorry, "balise" is the french word for "tag".

Comment: Here my controller :

Answer (score 0):

> public function membersHubHCUserAjaxAction(Request $request, $slug)
>       {
>           if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
>               list($user, $activeClub, $allUserClubs) = $this->manage_getBaseData($slug, 'cmember');
>               $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

```
        $allMembers = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Club\LinkClubUser')->getValidsMembersInClub($activeClub);

        $listMembers = [];
        foreach($allMembers as $m){
            $urlUser = $this->generateUrl('front_user_show', array('slug' => $m->getUser()->getSlug()));
            $fullname = $m->getUser()->getFullName();
            $headline = $m->getUser()->getHeadline();
            $manager = $this->get('assets.packages');
            // Gestion de l'image
            if($m->getUser()->getAvatarType()){
                if($m->getUser()->getAvatarType() == 1 && $m->getUser()->getLinkedinAvatarUrl() != null){
                    $imagePath =  $m->getUser()->getLinkedinAvatarUrl();
                }elseif($m->getUser()->getAvatarType() == 2){
                    $imagePath = $m->getUser()->getAvatarPath();
                }else{
                    $imagePath = $manager->getUrl('/images/avatar.png');//'web/images/avatar.png';
                }
            }else{
                $imagePath = $manager->getUrl('/images/avatar.png');//'web/images/avatar.png';
            }
```

Comment: I send in a ajax response an array with the members attributes . But i can't to get back the image path of each member in my twig file. Here my jquery :

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block jsfooter %}
        <script id="template" type="text/html">
            <div class="avatar_card">
                <div class="avatar avatar_medium content_bottom">
                    <div class="avatar_image">
                        <a data-href="urlUser" title="Voir le profil">
                            <img data-src="image" class="image_wrapper">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="avatar_content">
                        <h4 data-content="fullname"></h4>
                        <p data-content="headline"></p>
                        <p data-content="expertises"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="data"><span data-content="nbrWifeels"></span><br>{{ 'account-user-edit-clubs.wifeel'|transchoice(user.wifeelsProjects|length, {}, 'account-user-edit-clubs')}}</div>
                <div class="data"><span data-content="nbrWivalues"></span><br>{{ 'account-user-edit-clubs.wivalue'|transchoice(user.wivaluesProjects|length, {}, 'account-user-edit-clubs')}}</div>
                <div class="data"><span data-content="nbrProjects"></span><br>{{ 'account-user-edit-clubs.submitted-project'|transchoice(user.linkProjetUser|length, {}, 'account-user-edit-clubs')}}</div>
                <div class="data"><span data-content="nbrClubs"></span><br>{{ 'account-user-edit-clubs.club-member'|trans({}, 'account-user-edit-clubs')}}</div>
                <a data-href="urlStats" data-class="classBtn" data-content="comment"></a>
            </div>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('user_clubs_huddle_members_ajax',{slug:club.slug})}}",
                type:"json",
                method: "GET",
                success: function(response){
                    $('.avatar_card_grid').loadTemplate('#template', response, {append:true})
                }
            });
        </script>
```